# do something before [super init] in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to set a member variable in a derived object before i call [super init]. 
All I can find is that you should not do such a thing. My worakround, to do it anyhow, works, but actually I like to know what the consequences are when bending the rules. Or even better if there is a correct way to deal with this.

The Details:

I have several wrappers that bind a c++ object to an objective-c objec (mostly UI...View or UI...Controller)

```
@interface my_scrollview : UIScrollView
{
  my_c_class* m_p;
}
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame wrapper: (my_scrollview*) pWrap;
-(void) setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset;
@end
@implementation dwin_scrollview_ios
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame wrapper: (my_scrollview*) pWrap
{
  m_p = pWrap;    // illegal but works?
  return [super initWithFrame: frame];
  //m_p = pWrap;  // to late because [super init...] already called overriden func. 
}
```

In my overwritten setContentOffset-method I need to access my C++-Object.
The Problem arises because the initWithFrame internally initializes its content using setContentOffset. So this method is called before I could "legaly" set up the link to my c++-object.

I can implement my overrides with a check if m_p is set(luckily it's initialized to nil). But I have to synchronize the state of the view and my c++-object after the the init-method. In this example this is no big deal but other such realtions are much more complicated and I end up with lot of code that repeats steps of the initialization or otherwise brings me back in sync, although before the [super init...] I know I was in sync.

Is there a pattern to solve this correct (and elegant)?

Is it really so bad to int the pointer before the call to [super init..];?

(I assume one consequence is that this crashes if [super init] returns nil...? any other cases?)

Thanks in advance
Moritz

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but why is this illegal?  Swift encourages this kind of initialization.

Comment: eg. apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW58 I found other docs that say thesame but no one bothers to tell if it's a rule of thumb or why you cannot do that...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW58

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing magical about init methods in Objective-C. alloc returns an object of the class that you want, with all instance variables initialized to 0 / nil / NULL / 0.0 etc. Each init method then just executes the code that the developer has written.

There are things that are obviously stupid, like setting an instance variable of the superclass, then calling [super init] which promptly overwrites it. And you need to be aware that init doesn't necessarily return self, but a different object, in which case everything you've initialised in the base class before calling [super init] will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
// illegal but works?
```

No, it's not illegal. It's perfectly legitimate, although unconventional, to do stuff to an object before its superclass' initializer has been run. It may still lead to unexpected behavior and bugs, but it's not illegal per se. Sometimes it's even necessary, for example when you want to perform some computation and delegate the result of that computation to the superclass' initializer.

Answer (score -1):

**You are using wrong init**

try this:

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame wrapper: (my_scrollview*) pWrap
{
    self = [super initWithFrame: frame];
    if (self) {
        m_p = pWrap;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: `my_scrollview * scroll = [[my_scrollview alloc] initWithframe:....];
[scroll setContentOffset:....]
`

Comment: the point is that I want m_p already to be valid when initWithFrame calls other member-methods (in the example setContentOffset)